# Alterar objeto em outro método

Tags: java

Oque há de errado com alterar um objeto, que foi passado para outro método ?, ex:

```
public void doSomething(User user){
    edit(user);
    //...
    EntityManager.persist(user);
}

public void edit(User user){
    //...
    user.setName("new name");
}
```

Em geral todos dizem que a forma abaixo seria a "mais correta"

```
public void doSomething(User user){
    User updatedUser = edit(user);
    //...
    EntityManager.persist(updatedUser);
}

public User edit(User user){
    //...
    user.setName("new name");
    return user;
}
```

Mas oque não entendo é porque retornar a mesma instância do objeto alterado ? Alguns dizem que isso é menos propenso a erros, porque na primeira forma você acaba perdendo o "rastro" de onde o objeto está sendo alterado. Sinceramente não esse argumento não me convenceu.

Existe alguma "boa prática" para esses casos, ou seria mesmo uma questão ideológica de desenvolvedor ?

Comment: Quem diz? Cite uma fonte disto.

Comment: @bigown Na verdade isso é algo que venho ouvindo de algumas pessoas durante minha carreira, e só hoje resolvi questionar com mais detalhes essa questao.

Comment: Sempre que alguém diz algo pergunte porque. Peça para a pessoa mostrar para você o motivo daquilo. Em muitos casos ela está apenas repetindo o que ela ouviu de outra pessoa que está fazendo a mesma coisa até que chega em alguém que inventou uma maluquice qualquer. Questione na hora quando alguém vomita uma regra para você.

Answer (score 2):

Não é regra, você pode realizar alterações de um objeto passado pois ele é apenas um "ponteiro". Apenas tome cuidado nas bibliotecas e APIs, que você estiver usando.

Por exemplo suponha um projeto JPA/Hibernate, com o seguinte código:

```
 public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) { 
    entityManager.merge(emp);
    emp.setLastAccessTime(new Date());
 }
```

A nova instância de `new Date()` será persistida no banco de dados quando o contexto dessa transação terminar?

Não será persistida! Porque o método `object merge(object)` retorna uma instância que está no contexto persistent e não no detached. Dessa forma, o objeto passado como parâmetro continua não conversando com o context persistence do JPA, mas somente o seu retorno. Assim para que o código persistisse a nova data seria necessário fazer uma pequena alteração no código.

```
 public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) { 
    Employee empDB = entityManager.merge(emp);
    empDB.setLastAccessTime(new Date());
 }
```

Dessa forma quando a transação terminar a nova instância de Date será persistida.

Espero que tenha ajudado!